# connect QPushButton and QComboBox

Tags: qt, qcombobox, qpushbutton

How can I connect a `QPushButton` and a `QComboBox`?

I created a SLOT that accepts 2 parameters, a pointer to the `QComboBox` and the index of the selected item:

```
void modificaExp::eliminaExp(QComboBox *combo,int value)
{
   ......
    combo->removeItem(value);
   ....
}
```

the widgest are there:

```
QComboBox* combo=new QComboBox();
combo->addItem("ciao1");
combo->addItem("ciao44");
combo->addItem("ciao222");
combo->addItem("ciao555");

QPushButton* delButton=new QPushButton();
delButton->setText("delete");

   connect(delButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT( eliminaExp(combo,combo->currentIndex() )));
```

so, when I click on `delButton` the element stays there. I think there is a problem in the connect command, specifically I think than the slot is not called.

Comment: `connect` does not work this way. If you're using Qt4, you'll have to pass `combobox` to a slot somehow (make it a class member, or via `setProperty`). If you're using Qt5, you can switch to a 'new' version of `connect` and write a lambda.

Comment: thanks, you're right!! you save my project :D

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need this slot with two parameter?

Another simple way:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setupUi(this);

    connect(deleteButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(deleteSlot()));

}

void MainWindow::deleteSlot()
{
    comboBox->removeItem(comboBox->currentIndex());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The slot should have the same type and equal or less number of arguments than the signal
2. Declare the QComboBox and the QPushButton objects in the header 
   modificaexp.h

   ```
    private:
    QComboBox* combo;
    QPushButton* delButton;
   ```
3. modificaexp.cpp

   ```
   combo=new QComboBox();
   combo->addItem("ciao1");
   combo->addItem("ciao44");
   combo->addItem("ciao222");
   combo->addItem("ciao555");

   delButton=new QPushButton();
   delButton->setText("delete");

   connect(delButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT( eliminaExp()));
   ```
4. Modify the slot

   ```
    void modificaExp::eliminaExp()
    {           
       combo->removeItem(combo->currentIndex());        
    }
   ```
5. Refer the Qt signal slot [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html)

Comment: The same way i suggested =)

Comment: @t3ft3l--i. I dint realise that there was an answer until I submitted. +1 for u!! :)